# can ngrx store.dispatch be throttled / debounced or can ngrx actions be throttled / debounced?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using ngrx 6 with angular 6

In my ngrx store devtools I see that one of my actions is firing more often than I want. It's not breaking the app, its just cluttering the devtools output.

I am dispatching the action with:

```
this.store.dispatch(new RecentSearchesRequestedAction())
```

How can I best debounce / throttle this so that it does not dispatch more than once per second for example? Does ngrx have a built in solution? I know I could spend time working out why the action is firing so often but I don't really have time for that. What's best practice to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: If it is dispatched more than once, there must be some circular call due to effects or smth. Can you provide code of your reducer and effects? As far as I know there is no way to interfere how an action is dispatched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution would be to debounce whatever is calling this.store.dispatch, which would be outside ngrx.

You can throttle the *output* side of ngrx, for example:

```
this.store.select((x) => x.property)
.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000)
).subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

... would log the value of x.property at most once per second. But to stop the inputs, you need to throttle before the calls are made to dispatch.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complementary answer to the accepted one and dives into more details about where to actually place the debounce.

When working with `FormControl`s it is simple to debounce because of valueChanges ([example](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/http/search_with_switchmap)):

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
    .switchMap(term => this.searchService.search(term))
    .subscribe((result) => {
        this.result = result.items
    });
```

This relies on `switchMap` function which cancels existing calls and keeps the latest one.

When working with custom controls, cancellation typically requires custom code ([example for a Kendo control](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/debounce-valuechange/) which does not emit changes, but relies on events):

#### After value change directive that applies the debouncing

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[afterValueChanged]'
})
export class AfterValueChangedDirective implements OnDestroy {
  @Output()
  public afterValueChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input()
  public valueChangeDelay = 300;

  private stream: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    this.subscription = this.stream
      .pipe(debounceTime(this.valueChangeDelay))
      .subscribe((value: any) => this.afterValueChanged.next(value));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('valueChange', [ '$event' ])
  public onValueChange(value: any): void {
    this.stream.next(value);
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
<kendo-numerictextbox
  (afterValueChanged)="onAfterValueChange($event)"
  (valueChange)="onValueChange($event)">
</kendo-numerictextbox>

public onAfterValueChange(value: number): void {
   this.value = value;
}
```